# Firebase rules result in odd behaviour

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

For the Firebase rule set below.

```
"users": {

    //".read": "(auth != null) && (auth.uid === newData.child('id').val())",

  // A list of users and their associated metadata, which can be updated by the single user or a moderator.
  "$userId": {
    ".write": "(auth != null) && (auth.uid === $userId)",
    ".read": "(auth != null) && (auth.uid === $userId)",
    ".validate": "($userId === newData.child('id').val())",
    "invites": {
      // A list of chat invitations from other users, append-only by anyone.
      "$inviteId": {
        // Allow the user who created the invitation to read the status of the invitation.
        ".read": "(auth != null) && (auth.uid === data.child('fromUserId').val())",
        ".write": "(auth != null) && (!data.exists() || $userId === auth.uid || data.child('fromUserId').val() === auth.uid)",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['fromUserId','fromUserName','roomId']) && (newData.child('inviteId').val() === $inviteId)"
      }
    }
    }   
}
```

When I try the rules simulator as user 2456gd, the URL `/users/2456gd/` - validation step under `$userId` succeeds. But if try `/users/2456gd/invites/abcd2` - validation step under `$userId` fails.

The data I use:

```
{
"id":"2456gd",
"fromUserId":"2456gd",
"fromUserName":"abc",
"roomId":"family",
"inviteId":"abcd2"
}
```

Any possible explanation? And how to approach it.

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot of the Simulator Results Details]

Comment: What fails `read` or `write` or `both`?

Comment: read succeeds with the first url: /users/2456gd/, but fails at the second too.

Comment: It's a bit hard to parse the exact failure. Can you share a screenshot of your simulator with the JSON, the path you're reading, the error message and the auth token?

Comment: I have added the screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.... I don't really see what's wrong with this. Maybe someone else spots it. I'd normally put this type of check in the `.write` rule (it's not about data structure, but more about authorization). But that shouldn't make a different to the result.

Comment: `validate: "newData.hasChildren(['id'])"`

Comment: if I add the above validate statement. It fails too. So looks like a data structure issue?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this picture

[image: Validation failed]

The validation fails at `/users/$userId/` because the data there doesn't have `id` as its child. The data at `/user/$userId` looks something like this

```
{
    "invites": {
        "abcd2": {
            "id":"2456gd",
            "fromUserId":"2456gd",
            "fromUserName":"abc",
            "roomId":"family",
            "inviteId":"abcd2"
        }
    }
}
```

Since this data doesn't have `id` as its child validation fails. It has only one child that is `invites`.

Comment: @user2536851 Moving the `.validate` from `$userId` to `$inviteId` should work.